# What is the Assouad dimension of a complete unit ball?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

I have been recently exposed to the following definition of the Assouad dimension

> For any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^D$ and any $r>0$, let $B(x, r) =\{z:\|x−z\| \le r\}$ denote the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. The Assouad dimension of $S\subset\mathbb{R}^D$ is the smallest integer $d$ such that for any ball $B(x, r)\subset\mathbb{R}^D$, the $set\ B(x, r)\cap S$ can be covered by $2^d$ balls of radius $r/2$.

This value $d$ is supposed to be a measure of the 'intrinsic dimensionality' of a data $S \subset \mathbb{R}^D$.
Intuition dictates that it should be $D$ for truly $D$-dimensional $S$.

Let $S$ be the ball $B(x,r)$. I can't see how it can be covered by $2^d$ balls.

Comment: Where are you seeing this definition?  In particular, who is claiming that the Assouad dimension should be integer valued?

Comment: @Xander https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dasgupta/papers/rptree-stoc.pdf this is the paper in which i found it, the definition is in section 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Definitions

It might help if you start with a somewhat expanded (and rather complicated looking) definition.

> **Definition 1:**  Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $S \subseteq X$.  For any real numbers $r$ and $R$ with $0 < r < R$, let $\mathcal{N}_S(r,R)$ denote the number of balls of radius $r$ required to cover a ball of radius $R$ which is centered in $S$.  Define
> $$ \Delta_{\varepsilon,t}(S) := \sup\left\{ \frac{\log \mathcal{N}_S(r,R)}{\log(R/r)} \ \middle|\ 0 < r < R < \varepsilon\ \text{and}\ R > tr \right\}. $$
> The *Assouad dimension* of $S$ is given by
> $$ \dim_{\text{As}}(S) := \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \lim_{t\to\infty} \Delta_{\varepsilon,t}(S).$$

This particular formulation is *very* general—it makes sense in any metric space.  The essential idea is that you count the number of little balls which are *required* to cover a large ball, and ask how bad that can get as (1) the radii of the balls goes to zero but (2) the ratio between the radii of a large ball and a small ball goes to infinity.  This definition is taken from a paper by [H. Movahedi-Lankarani](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-116-02/S0002-9939-1992-1111436-3/).

It is worth noting that, contrary to what is asserted in the question, the Assouad dimension of a set $S$ is not necessarily an integer.  Indeed, it "typically" won't be an integer.

This characterization of the Assouad dimension is a little unwieldy, but it can be simplified a bit.  The simplification has the advantage of making the Assouad dimension "look" a bit more like the box-counting dimension, which may be written
$$\dim_{\text{box}}(S) = \inf\left\{ a \ \middle|\ \exists K>1 \text{ s.t. }\mathcal{N}_S(r) \le K\left( \frac{1}{r} \right)^a \text{ for all } 0 < r < 1 \right\}, $$
where $\mathcal{N}_S(r)$ is the number of balls of radius $r$ required to cover $S$.

> **Definition 2:** Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^D$ be compact (closed and bounded).  The *Assouad dimension* of $S$ is given by
> $$
> \dim_{\text{As}}(S) = \inf\left\{ a \ \middle|\ \exists K>1 \text{ s.t. }\mathcal{N}_S(r,R) \le K\left( \frac{R}{r} \right)^a \text{ for all } 0 < r < R < 1 \right\},
> $$
> where $\mathcal{N}_S(r,R)$ is as above.

This definition is (essentially) that given by [Jouni Luukkainen](http://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO199811919486026.page), [Eric Olson](https://msp.org/pjm/2002/202-2/p12.xhtml), [James Robinson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/dimensions-embeddings-and-attractors/3C621DA218BE433CEC5B0E9C558286F8), and others.  This characterization is nice, as it makes obvious the scaling relation—basically, we are looking for the "best" exponent such that the number of little balls needed to cover a big ball scales like the ratio of the two radii, rasied to that power.

#### Dimension of a Ball

There are a few results which I am going to state without proof:

1. For any integer $D$, we have $\dim_{\text{As}}(\mathbb{R}^D) = D$.
2. If $S\subseteq T$, then $\dim_{\text{As}}(S) \le \dim_{\text{As}}(T)$.

The first result follows, essentially, from a slightly more general theory, which I don't want to present here (this answer is already too long).  The second result should be "obvious"—if $S\subseteq T$, then any ball in $S$ is also a ball in $T$.  Thus
$$ \mathcal{N}_S(r,R) \le \mathcal{N}_T(r,R),$$
from which the result follows.

Now, suppose that $B = B(x,R)$ is a ball is a ball (either open or closed, it doesn't matter) in $\mathbb{R}^D$, and suppose for contradiction that $\dim_{\text{As}}(B) = a < D$.  This would imply that $B$ can be covered by $K(R/r)^a$ balls of radius $r$, and so
$$ \operatorname{vol}(B) \le K\left(\frac{R}{r} \right)^a \operatorname{vol}(B(0,r)), \tag{$\ast$}$$
where $\operatorname{vol}(B(x,r))$ denotes the $D$-dimensional volume (really, the Lebesgue measure) of a ball of radius $r$.  Note that this inequality does, actually, make sense:  the union of the $r$-balls contains $B$, so the volume of $B$ is bounded by the volume of the union.  But the union contains $M(R/r)^a$ $r$-balls, each of which has the same volume.

It follows from elementary calculus techniques that
$$ \operatorname{vol}(B(0,r)) = \Omega_D r^D, $$
where $\Omega_D$ is a constant which depends on $D$.  For example:
$$
\Omega_1 = 2, \qquad
\Omega_2 = \pi, \qquad
\Omega_3 = \frac{4}{3}\pi, \qquad
\text{etc.}
$$
Substituting this into ($\ast$) gives
$$
K\left(\frac{R}{r} \right)^a \operatorname{vol}(B(0,r))
\le K\Omega_N \left(\frac{R}{r} \right)^a r^D
= K\Omega_N R^a r^{D-a}. $$
But $D-a > 0$ by hypothesis, and this inequality must hold for *all* $r > 0$, from which it follows that $r^{D-a}$ can be made arbitrarily close to zero by a choice of $r$.  But then
$$ \operatorname{vol}(B)
\le K\Omega_N R^a r^{D-a} $$
for all $r < R$, which implies that $\operatorname{vol}(B) = 0$.  This is a contradiction, therefore we cannot have $\dim_{\text{As}}(B) < D$.  In other words, $\dim_{\text{As}}(B) \ge D$.

On the other hand, since $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^D$, it must be the case that
$$\dim_{\text{As}}(B) \le \dim_{\text{As}}(\mathbb{R}^D) = D, $$
and so
$$ D \le \dim_{\text{As}}(B) \le D
\implies \dim_{\text{As}}(B) = D. $$

#### Futher Reading

I gave a talk on this topic a few years ago.  Some slightly more detailed definitions (and a more terse version of the above argument) can be found in [the notes for that talk](http://yozh.org/docs/assouad_notes.pdf).  For further reading, I would once again suggest Robinson's book:

*Robinson, James C.*, Dimensions, embeddings, and attractors, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 186. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-89805-8/hbk). xii, 205 p. (2011). [ZBL1222.37004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1222.37004).